# How to publish or push the live stream to RTMP-Nginx server using php and FFmpeg?

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I want to push the live stream to the RTMP-Nginx server. I am recording the webcam and sending it to the PHP running server using the socket but couldn't find the proper way to push the stream on the RTMP-Nginx server. I am appending the stream after receiving through the socket. I have used this

`ffmpeg -re -i uploads/test.webm -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -maxrate 1500k -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://x.xx.xxx.xx/live/xxx`

to push on the RTMP-Nginx server. But it's executing on the very first received packet of the video stream and then terminated. I know It's not working with a continuous appended video stream. may be FFmpeg reading as a whole. Hoping for the right direction. Thanks in advance.